# What is the best program for simple data visualization, especially for "boolean" operators/simple correlations?

Tags: correlation, data-visualization

I would like to preface this by saying I have no prior statistics or datviz experience so please forgive me for not knowing all the correct terminology. The project I am working on is just for fun and I have suddenly discovered I am out of my depth!

I have created a survey with mostly multiple choice questions and a couple of select-all-that-apply questions, and I have a spreadsheet with the responses. I know there are hundreds of data visualization tools out there, but I have a specific need, and my lack of experience in the field means I'm not even sure how to search for what I need. What I am hoping for, specifically, is a program that will not only allow me to visualize the data, but specifically to include simple correlation constraints. For example, I want to see only the answers to question b that were provided by people who also answered "yes" to question a. I have the basic pie charts and such for the answers already as they are provided by the survey platform I used, but the overlap in the questions - did people who answered "yes" to question A also answer "yes" to question B - is actually the *entire* focus of the survey, so it's crucial that I can sort/represent this fairly easily. I'm really only looking for a pie chart here, like I said it's very simple stuff. It's simply the need to show "answers to question b for those who ALSO answered yes to question a" that's tripping me up.

I know this is something that would be easy to do in advanced stats processing software but I am, as I said, a little out of my depth and am hoping for something fairly simple that will not require learning R or Matlab. This is legitimately just a project I'm doing for fun on a blog that got somewhat more popular than I anticipated, and while I originally intended to simply manually input the data into some kind of chart maker, I am at the point where I have too much data to comfortably manually count or input.

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide. I am but a simple nerd who got out of their depth!

Comment: This kind of work is exactly what Power BI and Tableau were made for. My go-to is Power BI, but I think there are free versions of both.

Comment: @NickKoprowicz Thank you! I'll look into those!